# Is hardware assembling questions off the Server Fault's focus?

Tags: discussion, serverfault

Can I ask questions related to 'assembling server racks'?

Comment: Thanks for asking here first by the way, seriously, you've no idea how many people just wade in without thought.

Comment: Racks perhaps but servers nope.

Comment: What do you need to know?

Comment: @ewwhite The main thing for me is the wiring part. For example, I got a SuperMicro motherboard, and with in it comes an A3 paper indicating what type of RAM, and CPU(s) it requires, which is pretty strait forward. Also I can check what sort of chassis it needs, but how to wire it, based on the board specification, is a challenge.

Comment: @DaveRose That's stuff that's off-topic (how to build your own server).

Comment: You might want to change the title of your question. It looks like your question is (is X **off** topic), and your full question is (is X **on** topic). A yes/no response is hard to understand when you're asking the question both ways.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Almost certainly Yes. Unless you're trying to do something hack-ish, unsupportable, or completely weird.

For example, Ikea Table "Racks" would be off-topic. But assembly of 0U PDUs would be on-topic...

Comment: With one caveat: Assembling a rack in the basement of your home might be frowned upon...

Comment: I have an HP 10000 Series rack in the basement of my home, my wife is the only one frowning.

Comment: Um... I used an Ikea table to hold a patch panel a couple months ago when my rack was delayed in shipping. http://i.stack.imgur.com/nzMV1.jpg

Comment: @Ward I was thinking of Ikea's Lack table, which is almost exactly 19" wide and about 31" deep. Details: https://wiki.eth0.nl/index.php/LackRack

Comment: @Chris Yeah, I've seen those, just thought it was funny timing that I did recently use an Ikea table "professionally."